# Redirect user before success callback is received

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/script.php",
    data: { "action" : "importData" },
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function() {
        window.location.href = "/next-page";
    }
} );
```

When a user lands on this page, ajax will trigger the php script which takes about 15 seconds to complete. Rather than having the user wait for the script to complete and then redirect them, I want to get some type of confirmation that the script has been triggered, then redirect the user without waiting for the entire script to complete. The results of the script isnt used until many minutes later in the workflow.

Is this possible? How to do so?

Comment: by default it wont wait, just move the redirect to after the call (remove from success)

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax()` returns the `XMLHttpRequest` instance:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/script.php',
  data: {action: 'importData'},
  cache: false,
  success: function(){
    location = '/next-page';
  }
});
/* to test if problem is jQuery remove this line and take comments out
var px = xhr.onreadystatechange;
*/
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  //if(px)px();
  if(xhr.readyState === 3 && xhr.status === 200){ // look at Properties -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
    // do stuff here with xhr.readyState less than 4
  }
}
```

Valid `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` property values can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Note that if you redirect the user, JavaScript on the current page stops. The page that your user is redirected to may have it's own JavaScript.

Comment: xhr.onreadystatechange is not being called and hence my window.location.href = "/next-page"; within that if statement is not being executed?

Comment: `xhr.onreadystatechange` is automatically called when the `readyState` changes for that specific instance of the `XMLHttpRequest`, `xhr` in your case. The `success` method within `$.ajax({})` fires when `xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)`. If `success` is not executing, it is either because your code happening within the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function is doing something to prevent it, or `jQuery` used the same assignment methodology I did, as opposed to `xhr.addEventListener`. If it's a `jQuery` problem I have the solution anyways.